# How to get URL parameter from a React Router path

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I am creating a simple CRUD recipe app on the MERN(Mongo, Express, React, and Node) stack and I made the mistake of retrofitting React Router after I built out all the other logic which has been a little painful.

I can't seem to access the parameter for my individual recipes from the Route

`<Route exact path='/recipe/:recipeId' render={() => (<Recipe getRecipe={this.props.getRecipe} edit={this.props.updateRecipe} />)} />`

Here is the Recipe Component referenced in the Route:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import IngredientsList from './ingredients-list.js';


export default class Recipe extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.dir(this.props);
    let id = this.props.match.params.recipeId;
    this.setState({ 
        recipe: this.props.getRecipe(id),
    });

};
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.dir(this.props);
    let id = this.props.match.params.recipeId;

    this.setState({ 
        recipe: this.props.getRecipe(id),
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="recipe-display container-fluid">
            <div className="recipe-header">
                <h1>{this.state.recipe.name}</h1>
                <h3>By {this.state.recipe.author}</h3>
                <hr />
                <h4>Category: {this.state.recipe.category}</h4>
                <p className="recipe-date">Created: {moment(this.state.recipe.createdDate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')}</p>
                <p>Description: {this.state.recipe.description}</p>
                <div className="recipe-btns">                       
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-sm close-recipe"
                        onClick={this.props.close}
                        title="Close this Recipe">Close</button>
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-success pull-right btn-sm edit-recipe"
                        onClick={this.props.edit}
                        title="Edit this Recipe">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="recipe-body">
                <div className="recipe-timing">
                    <p>Prep Time: {this.state.recipe.prepTime}</p>
                    <p>Cook Time: {this.state.recipe.cookTime}</p>
                </div>
                <div className='ingredients panel panel-info'>
                    <div className='panel-heading'>Ingredients:</div>
                    <div className='panel-body'>
                        <div className="ingredients-list">
                            <IngredientsList ingredients={this.state.recipe.ingredients} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='directions panel panel-success'>
                    <div className='panel-heading'>Directions:</div>
                    <div className='panel-body'>
                        {this.state.recipe.directions}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I've tried calling `this.props.match.params.recipeId` in a few different ways, in the constructor in the various lifecycle functions etc. The error I'm currently getting is

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

I'm probably missing something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Route exact path='/recipe/:recipeId' render={(props) => (<Recipe getRecipe={this.props.getRecipe} edit={this.props.updateRecipe} {...props} />)} />
```

The problem with your original code is, you did not send the props to `<Recipe />`. If you use `render`, you have to send the props manually.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I knew it was something simple.